# Select a range of rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame('n' = integer())
df['A', 1] <- 2
df['B', 1] <- 5
df['C', 1] <- 3
df['D', 1] <- 8
df['E', 1] <- 4
df['F', 1] <- 6
df['G', 1] <- 9
```

How can I select rows D through F? I could just do `df[c('D', 'E', 'F'), 1]`, but the dataframe I'm actually working with has hundreds of rows, so I don't want to manually type in each row name. I tried `df['D':'F', 1]` and `df[c('D':'F'), 1]`, but those throw errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to a get a sequence from the location of `D` to the location of `F`, and index using that sequence:

```
f <- \(n,r1,r2) seq(which(n==r1), which(n==r2))

df[f(rownames(df),"D", "F"),,drop=F]
```

Output:

```
  n
D 8
E 4
F 6
```

Depending on your actual large dataset, there might be different ways to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @langtang is good, if the letters you're after are a single, contiguous set and the rows are in sequence.  If they are out of sequence or if you want to build up the rows to pull, then this may be a more flexible option.

Essentially:

1. Build up a vector of the letters you're after.
2. Select them using `dplyr::filter()`

   library(dplyr)

   letter_sel <- c(LETTERS[which(LETTERS == "D"):which(LETTERS == "F")],
   "G")

   filter(df, rownames(df) %in% letter_sel)